# Question on congruence of diagonal matrices over $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Consider all real $n\times n$ diagonal matrices of the form

$$ \Lambda =\begin{pmatrix}
   1 \\
   & \ddots  \\
   &  & 1 \\
   &&& -1 \\
   &&&& \ddots \\
   &&&&& -1 \\
   \end{pmatrix} $$

where the number of $1$s equals $p(\Lambda)$

I've a basic question- can two such matrices $\Lambda$, $\Lambda^{'}$ with $p(\Lambda)\neq p(\Lambda^{'})$ be congruent over $\mathbb R$?

i.e. can we find an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $P$ over $\mathbb R$ s.t. $\Lambda^{'}=P^{\rm T}\Lambda P$ ? Many thanks.

Comment: No, by [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: So congruence implies that the two matrices are equal?

Comment: Not at all, how are you getting that?

Comment: Because you are saying that if $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda^{'}$ are congruent then $p(\Lambda)=p(\Lambda^{'})$.

Comment: Consider $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0& -1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$.They are congruent, but not equal.

Comment: Yes but it's just the way I defined the $\Lambda$s.

Comment: You said that congruent implies equality. I gave a counter-example to this. If you mean something else, then say something else.

Comment: I meant whether congruence implies that the two matrices (of the form I defined above in the question) are equal. Sorry for not making this clearer.

Comment: Well, yes, that's because they both start with $1$s and they will both start the $-1$s at the same time because the number of $1$s of one is the same as the number of $1$s of the other, because you're assuming they're congruent.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: previous answer about spectra was incorrect, I confused $PAP^{-1}$ with $PAP^T$.

The relevant information is given in Git Gud's link in the comments to Sylvester's law of inertia.

Comment: Maybe you mean that congruent matrices have the same *inertia*.

Comment: @Algebraic Reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia), I don't see that meaning anywhere. [Meanwhile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_matrix). If "inertia" is supposed to refer to the number of positive/negative eigenvalues, well, I'm not referring just to signs, but the whole multiset of eigenvalues, which is a much stronger claim, so I don't see why I should be referring to "inertia."

Comment: Conjugating a matrix does not preserve the spectrum. Nor do congruent matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @GitGud Yes it does. However I just realized we are not speaking of $PAP^{-1}$ but rather of $P^T AP$, so I will have to edit my answer.

Comment: @whacka If with conjugating a matrix $A$ you mean the product $P^TAP$, then it doesn't. If you mean something else, then I take back my words.

Comment: @GitGud Right, I mean conjugation in the group-theoretic sense ($PAP^{-1}$).